# eclipse e4 Dark Theme: How to style widgets created by FormToolKit with css

Tags: css, themes, styling, e4

In out project, we use org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit to create dialog and forms. Now we want to use the CSS theme ability of eclipse e4 to create a Dark Theme for out eclipse RCP application. 
I researched for hints about styling these widgets like "Section" but could not find information online. 
Has anybody experience or information about how to style these FormToolkit-created widget as they seem to use the OS-given system colors.
Other components accept the styling as applied according to Eclipse4CSS tutorials. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can just use the name of a control (such as `Section`) as the CSS selector, so

```css
Section
{
   ....
}
```

The `org.eclipse.ui.forms` plug-in defines a number of additional CSS attributes for `Section`, `Form` and `ExpandableComposite`

So the Eclipse dark theme has

```css
Form {
    text-background-color: #505F70; 
    tb-toggle-hover-color: #313538;
    tb-toggle-color: #313538;
    h-hover-full-color: #313538;
    h-hover-light-color: #313538;
    h-bottom-keyline-2-color: #313538;
    h-bottom-keyline-1-color: #313538;
    swt-background-mode: 'force';
}

Section {
       background-color: #4F5355;
       color: #AEBED0;
       background-color-titlebar: #4F5355;
       background-color-gradient-titlebar: #4F5355;
       border-color-titlebar: #4F5355;
}
```